# keyboard input in C# with razer switchblade sdk

Tags: c#, sdk

I cannot figure out how to accept keyboard input in the razer switchblade sdk.
In the documentation it shows you how to do it in C++ but I cannot figure out how to do it in the C# wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out [SharpBlade](http://sharpblade.net/)?  It's a great framework for using SwitchBlade UI with your apps, written in C#.

The following gets you going with keyboard capture using SharpBlade:

```
SharpBlade.Switchblade sbInstance = SharpBlade.Switchblade.Instance;
sbInstance.StartKeyboardCapture(Control, Boolean);
```

Comment: It should be noted this requires a WPF or WinForms control `Control` that input is forwarded to. If you want to simply capture input and handle it yourself via the [Switchblade events](http://sharpblade.net/docs/?topic=html/Events_T_SharpBlade_Switchblade.htm) you can enable it with the [KeyboardCapture property](http://sharpblade.net/docs/?topic=html/P_SharpBlade_Switchblade_KeyboardCapture.htm).